# Where are Zookeeper files actually present?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am currently working with SolrCloud and have set up Zookeeper on a server. To create a collection in SolrCloud, I upload a configset in Zookeeper and use it to create a collection. On the zookeeper server, I use Zookeeper's CLI to view the config files as follows: -

```
zk@ip-some-ip-some-ip:/opt/zookeeper/bin$ ./zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:9983
/usr/bin/java
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9983
[zk: 127.0.0.1:9983(CONNECTED) 0] 
[zk: 127.0.0.1:9983(CONNECTED) 0] ls /configs
[_default, config_1, config_2]
[zk: 127.0.0.1:9983(CONNECTED) 1]
```

I tried searching for /configs directory within all zookeeper directories but couldn't find it. Where is it actually present on the system?

I tried searching for the `configs` directory as follows: -

```
find /var/zookeeper/ -name "configs"
find /opt/zookeeper/ -name "configs"
```

but didn't find anything.

I don't have any zookeeper directories anywhere else on the system.

Please let me know if any other information is needed from my end. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zookeeper keeps its data in-memory. From the [documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperOver.html),

> Unlike a typical file system, which is designed for storage, ZooKeeper data is kept in-memory, which means ZooKeeper can acheive high throughput and low latency numbers.

Transaction logs are stored in [Zookeeper's data directory](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#The+Data+Directory)